# Looking for daily user activity from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I want to find the Daily Active Users, which in each application differs how these are calculated. In my case, I have multiple tables where a user could have had an activity.

I've been able to do a LEFT JOIN in one of the tables, but I don't know how to incorporate the rest of the tables to get the activity that happened the last 30 days.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(user_video_plays.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
    count(*)
FROM
    `users`
    INNER JOIN `subscriptions` ON `users`.`id` = `subscriptions`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `user_video_plays` ON `users`.`id` = `user_video_plays`.`user_id`
WHERE
    `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND `subscriptions`.`chargebee_status` <> 'cancelled'
    AND `user_video_plays`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2022-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(user_video_plays.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I have 2 more tables where the user could have activity: forum_posts and forum_post_replies. How can I incorporate them into my query so I get the activity grouped by day?

I've prepared a DB fiddle with the structure and some sample data, as well as my query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ppRaWP7SPDURm8dePyAkEr/0

Thank you

**UPDATE 1:** Looking at @Luuk answer, I realized that also somehow we need to make this unique. In the following fiddle, I've simplified the data but user_video_plays have 3 plays from the same user and that shouldn't count as 3 but one:  https://dbfiddle.uk/ZszSND-H - I think this is easy on my single table query, with a unique, but I should have this into consideration with the 3 extra tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `forum_posts`:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(user_video_plays.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
    count(*) countUsers,
    count(`user_video_plays`.`user_id`) videoPlays,
    count(`forum_posts`.`user_id`) forumPosts
FROM
    `users`
    INNER JOIN `subscriptions` ON `users`.`id` = `subscriptions`.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `user_video_plays` ON `users`.`id` = `user_video_plays`.`user_id` 
                                AND `user_video_plays`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2022-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-31 23:59:59'
    LEFT JOIN `forum_posts` ON `users`.`id` = `forum_posts`.`user_id` 
                           AND `forum_posts`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2022-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-31 23:59:59'
WHERE
    `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    AND `subscriptions`.`chargebee_status` <> 'cancelled'
    
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(user_video_plays.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

NOTE: I moved `AND` user_video_plays`.`created_at `BETWEEN ....` from the WHERE-clause to the ON-clause of the LEFT JOIN.

for the output, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y35cu5wY)

Can you can do the other table yourself, following this example?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luuk. I was looking into it, and it seems that even my initial query has a problem. If the same user has 3 plays, it will count as 3 “active users”. I’ve simplified the data/query here to point this case: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZszSND-H